# Как сделать scrolling position:absolute элементов (CSS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Решил написать чат, и хочу, чтоб сообщения отображались снизу вверх.
Вот `html` и `css`:

```css
/*Блок для вывода сообщений, который должен скроллиться*/

.correspondence {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: #346ABC;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*Свойства для сообщений отправителя*/

.temp-login-user-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.temp-login-user-message>p {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #24BC21;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.temp-login-user-message>img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


/*Свойства для сообщений других пользователей*/

.temp-other-users-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.temp-other-users-message>p {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFBFB;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.temp-other-users-message>img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="correspondence">
  <section class="temp-login-user-message">
    <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" class="user-photo">
    <p class="user-message">LOL!</p>
  </section>
  <section class="temp-other-users-message">
    <img src="img/unknown_female.png" alt="user-photo" class="user-photo">
    <p class="user-message">Agree! =)</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

В `js`, при вводе нового сообщения и отправки его, я вычисляю у каждого блока для сообщений его отступ снизу (`bottom`) от родителя (`.correspondence`) и прибавляю к этим значениям `100px`. Однако `scroll` у блока для просмотра сообщений (`.correspondence`) не работает. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ну это же просто. Нужно сделать родителя абсолютным, а ребёнка релативным. У релативки скролл задать явно или опираться на вложенный контент

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Делал кастомный чат тут https://rapidlanding.digital/. Посмотри , там основная идея в том, что есть фиксированная область сообщений с overflow-y: scroll. При появлении нового сообщения она просто крутится в самый низ при помощи JS.

Comment: А можете объяснить, зачем там вообще весь этот изврат с абсолютным позиционированием?

Comment: @Инквизитор я только начал изучать вёрстку,и мне показалось это единственным решением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высота родителя абсолютных элементов должна быть конкретной.

> и прибавляю к этим значениям 100px

прибавляйте их и к высоте `.container`.

```js
/* Песочница */
const [ container, block, input, button ] = [...document.querySelectorAll(".container, .correspondence, input, button")];

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const section = document.createElement("section");
  section.classList.add("temp-login-user-message");
  section.innerHTML = `
      <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" class="user-photo">
      <p class="user-message">${input.value}</p>
  `;
  block.appendChild(section);
  [...block.children].forEach((child, index) => child.style.bottom = (index * 100) + "px");
  block.style.height = (block.children.length * 100) + "px";
  container.scrollTop += 100;
})
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

/*Блок для вывода сообщений, который должен скроллиться*/

.container {
  height: 80vh;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: #346ABC;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.correspondence {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}


/*Свойства для сообщений отправителя*/

.temp-login-user-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.temp-login-user-message>p {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #24BC21;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.temp-login-user-message>img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


/*Свойства для сообщений других пользователей*/

.temp-other-users-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.temp-other-users-message>p {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFBFB;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.temp-other-users-message>img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="correspondence">
    <section class="temp-login-user-message">
      <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" class="user-photo">
      <p class="user-message">LOL!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="temp-other-users-message">
      <img src="img/unknown_female.png" alt="user-photo" class="user-photo">
      <p class="user-message">Agree! =)</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!--Песочница-->
  <div>
    <input type="text" /> <button>Send</button>
  </div>
  <!--/Песочница-->
</div>
```

Comment: Автор вроде хотел сообщения снизу вверх. Разве это не означает "старые ниже, новые выше"?

Comment: @Инквизитор да, означатает)

Comment: @Инквизитор в стандартном понимании "сообщения снизу вверх" разве не реверсивный вывод, где новые сообщения снизу? вижу, что автор вопроса подтвердил Ваши слова, но всё же. но в любом случае, на вопрос ответ дан. а то что Вы заметили - это лишь песочница. у автора свой обработчик вывода. обновил ответ убрав `reverse()`

Comment: "Снизу вверх" в стандартном понимании означает нисходящий порядок сортировки. В случае сортировки по датам - более поздние выше.
Но то ладно, теперь меня мучает вопрос - а зачем весь этот пляс с позиционированием? Почему нельзя было просто аппендить чайлды в контейнер, а порядок задать с помощью CSS `position:flex` и  `order`?

Comment: @Инквизитор если бы здесь все формулировали свои вопросы с такими подробностями - то я бы и этот воспринял буквально. Потому что с помощью `CSS` список не сделаешь виртуальным и блокам нужны позиции.

Comment: список  виртуальный - это вообще что такое?

Comment: Я попробовал выкинуть абсолюты и вставить флекс - все работает не хуже, чем в принятом ответе. добавляются сообщения, скроллинг, и все такое. Так и не нашел, в чем именно необходимость позиционирования абсолютом, а также флоатов.

Comment: @Инквизитор виртуализированный*
по поводу вопросов про позиционирование: задавайте их выше. я не автор сего стиля и вопрос от него к сообществу состоял не в этом.